# How to make a click function on parent element and have child element do something else without trigger parent

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to make a table in which my `<tr>` acts as a parent element, inside my `<tr>` I have a list of `<td>` elements, in which I want that all of them triggers when `<tr>` is clicked, except for one `<td>`, for that specific `<td>` i have 3 `<span>`'s thas has an individual trigger.

The problem is that I have both a click function on my `<tr>` and for my `<span>`'s, and of course when I click the `<span>` the `<tr>` also triggers because is the parent, I don't want this to happen, I want that when my `<span>`'s are clicked the parent doesn't trigger, just the `<span>`'s

I have a lot of `<td>`'s and I'm trying to avoid making each `<td>` a click function to do the same thing, except for that last `<td>`

Is it possible?

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="parentdiv">
         <td>something</td>
         <td style="width:30%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
         <td class="child"><span class="icon1"> icon1 </span><span class="icon2">icon2 </span><span class="icon3">icon3</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(".parentdiv").click(function () { 
 alert( 'clicked on parent' );

            });

$(".icon1").click(function () { 
     alert( 'clicked on icon 1' );

            });

$(".icon2").click(function () { 
  alert( 'clicked on icon 2' );

            });

$(".icon3").click(function () { 
 alert( 'clicked on icon 3' );

            });
```

And here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxyBLO)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling out.

```js
$(".parentdiv").click(function() {
  alert('clicked on parent');
});

$(".icon1").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('clicked on icon 1');
});

$(".icon2").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('clicked on icon 2');
});

$(".icon3").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('clicked on icon 3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentdiv">
      <td>something</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
      <td class="child"><span class="icon1"> icon1 </span><span class="icon2">icon2 </span><span class="icon3">icon3</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the click event from propagating to the parent with `stopPropagation()`. For example:

```
$(".icon1").click(function (event) { 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    // your code here...
});
```